# can't align list correctly

Tags: python, html, css, django

[image]

as you can see my list aligns some kind randomly and i dnot know why. Any ideas?

html:

```
{% if shop_name %}
      <ol>
        {% for library in shop_name %}
        <li>Video Library Info</li>
        <ul>
          <li>Name : {{library.shop_name}}</li>
          <li>Adress : {{library.adress}}</li>
          {% comment %} <button id="btn_goto" onclick="">Select</button> {% endcomment %}
        </ul>
        {% endfor %}
      </ol>
      {% else %}
      <p>ERROR</p>
      {% endif %}
```

css code:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFA000;
    background-color: #911E42;
}

ol {
    display: table;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ul {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    text-align: left;
}
```

so at css i typed that text in list should be aligned on left side but still it does'nt help and it aligns randomly as i think. The thing i need to perfom is to align every li from ul on left side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting `display: table;` might make your life easier and if that does not work. Try using `display: flex` on the parent and using `justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center;` to have it in the middle

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `display: table` from the `ul` selector and everything should be properly aligned.